# How to make Catalog used Group

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

How to organized report for Catalog 
For parameter etc(id= 1,2..)
I must get FRONT PAGE for `id=1`, then from the next page, data in table for this parameter id = 1.
Then, for the next `id = 2` I must get data for FRONT PAGE for id = 2,then from the next page, data for this parameter id =2.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4lx9.png]
This is the **front page** in jasperstudio https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAtCv.png 
and  **subreport**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVRRM.png

For `route_id=200` and `trafo_id in (1,2),` I must get front page with data for `segment_id`, then tables for `trafo_id =1`, then front page with data for `trafo_id = 2`, then tables for `trafo_id`.

Problem is, I get front page with data for `trafo_id =1`, then front page for `trafo_id=2`, then tables for `segment_id=1`, tables `for_segment_id=2`,then repeat it all again (front page and tables )

The **jrxml** is:

```
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="billing_group" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <parameter name="route" class="java.util.Collection"/>
    <parameter name="order_string" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{order_id}.toString()]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="from_dt" class="java.sql.Date">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{from_dt}]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="fam_id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <parameter name="prva_strana" class="java.lang.Boolean">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[null]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString language="SQL">...
    <field name="COUNT(T.SEGMENT_ID)" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="ORDER_UCODE" class="java.lang.String"/>...
    <variable name="COUNT(T.SEGMENT_ID)" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Group1" calculation="DistinctCount">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{COUNT(T.SEGMENT_ID)}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="Group1" isStartNewPage="true" isResetPageNumber="true" keepTogether="true">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{TRAFO_ID}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="720" splitType="Prevent">
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="130" y="503" width="40" height="30" uuid="0c6aecad-8db9-46f6-9c63-0ecee3a70d53">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                        <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[DV:]]></text>
                </textField>
                ...
                <staticText>
                ...
                <textField evaluationTime="Group" evaluationGroup="Group1">
                    <reportElement x="300" y="590" width="100" height="30" uuid="1f966c8a-b52a-487e-a8f9-d9bf7f1fc506"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{COUNT(T.SEGMENT_ID)}]]></textFieldExpression>
            ...
    </group>
    <group name="Group2" isStartNewPage="true" isResetPageNumber="true" keepTogether="true">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{SEGMENT_ID}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
                <subreport>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <group name="Group3" isStartNewPage="true" keepTogether="true">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{ROUTE_ID}]]></groupExpression>
```

Comment: please explain more , and add some screen shots of the required table

Comment: And add the jrxml that you have been trying.

Comment: The jrxml is not complete but the solution i think is in using correct groupExpression and printWhenExpression, remember also to sort your data so that the grouping works as excepted.